# @each-loop using map-get( )

Tags: sass

I am trying to use > ***map-get ( )*** with **@each-loop** to execute this code but I get an error, please help.

```
$names: (
    (
        "name": "name-1",
        "filename": "name-1.jpg",
        "color": "blue",
    ),

    (
        "name": "name-2",
        "filename": "name-2.jpg",
        "color": "red",
    )
);

@each $name in $names {
    $name: map-get($names, "name");
    $filename: map-get($names, "filename");
    $color: map-get($names, "color");

    .#{$name} {
        background-image: url("#{$filename}");
        color: $color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error 'cause you are not looping real maps (http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps).

You could use a nested map to resolve your problem. Something like this:

```
$names: (
    layout-1: (
        name: "name-1",
        filename: "name-1.jpg",
        color: blue
    ),

    layout-2: (
        name: "name-2",
        filename: "name-2.jpg",
        color: red
    )
);


@each $key, $value in $names {
  .#{map-get($value, name)} {
    background-image: url("#{map-get($value, filename)}");
    color: map-get($value, color);
  }
}
```

Comment: My whole code was wrong.Thank you very much.Thanks for the link too.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$names` list does not need keys. You can define the variable keys when you loop through the nested list, you also do not need to surround them in quotations as if they were `strings`. In the `@each` loop once you define each variable key in your list you can use each variable inside the brackets.

```
//-Updated SASS List, included list in name to make it more clear.
$names-list: (
  (
    name-1,
    name-1,
    blue
  ),

  (
    name-2,
    name-2,
    red
  )
);

//-Updated @each loop, defined variable keys for each item in the list.
@each $name, $fileName, $color in $names-list {
    .#{$name} {
       background-image: url('#{$fileName}.jpg');
       color: color;
     }

 }
 //-The code above compiles to the following CSS Classes with the properties defined inside
 .name-1 {
     background-image: url("name-1.jpg");
    color: color;
  }

 .name-2 {
   background-image: url("name-2.jpg");
   color: color;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. That was helpful especially in regards to readability and writing  less code.